# Javascript/Jquery to add mouse and touch draggable/Swipeable scrolling in flex horizontal scrolling div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm creating a webpage which has a flex horizontal scrolling container.
I want to add drag functionality to drag/Swipe to scroll, is there an solution for this?

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  width: 400px;
}

.flex-child {
  margin-right: 10px;
  background-color: yellow;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-child"> One </div>
  <div class="flex-child"> Two </div>
  <div class="flex-child"> Three </div>
  <div class="flex-child"> Four </div>
  <div class="flex-child"> Five </div>
  <div class="flex-child"> Six </div>
  <div class="flex-child"> One </div>
  <div class="flex-child"> Two </div>
  <div class="flex-child"> Three </div>
  <div class="flex-child"> Four </div>
  <div class="flex-child"> Five </div>
  <div class="flex-child"> Six </div>
  <div class="flex-child"> One </div>
  <div class="flex-child"> Two </div>
  <div class="flex-child"> Three </div>
  <div class="flex-child"> Four </div>
  <div class="flex-child"> Five </div>
  <div class="flex-child"> Six </div>
  <div class="flex-child"> One </div>
  <div class="flex-child"> Two </div>
  <div class="flex-child"> Three </div>
  <div class="flex-child"> Four </div>
  <div class="flex-child"> Five </div>
  <div class="flex-child"> Six </div>
</div>
```

Here i added a sample example of what i created.
i hide the scrollbar with css but i want to drag/Swipe the flex-container to scroll and view all the flex-child.

Comment: what you have tried for drag or swipe code?

Comment: This CodePen seems relevant: https://codepen.io/toddwebdev/pen/yExKoj